# Strange math with rounding and multiplying

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I have an odd problem.  I'm grabbing numbers from the web audio API, what I get out is a constant list of:

3.1051260268969075e-28 etc etc

I want to round that figure, but using:

```
Math.round(magAmount);
```

Always returns 0.  magAmount is the variable I store the number in.  Another odd thing, if I multiply the number by 5 I get a value lower than the original, in this case 1.5525630134484537e-27.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you don't know what that little e-28 at the end of the number means.

Comment: Yeah, ignore me I missed that.  Fresh morning, problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math.round() will round to the next integer, so rounding 0.0000000000..00001 (which you are doing) will round to 0.

also e-27 is bigger than e-28, so your multiply is correct

Answer (score 5):

That number is 5 times bigger.

e-28 is smaller than e-27

Answer (score 4):

Note that `e-28` is `*10^-28`, so there's nothing strange in your code.

And since this number is tiny, rounding it will certainly returns a `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Round to what precision? If you want

3.1051260268969075e-28 -> 3.1e-28 then

Math.round(3.1051260268969075e-28 * 1.0e+29) * 1.0e-29